# Android - Cannot get priority of IntentFilter

Tags: java, android, intentfilter

In my program I search for packages that match a specific intent.
From the list of ResolveInfo I get, I then try and order the packages according to the priority of their IntentFilter. But when I use the intentFilter.getPriority() method, it always returns 0, even though different priority values are used in the manifest of the targeted packages.

Here is an example of a Manifest:

```
<intent-filter
          priority='100'>
        <action
            name='com.gsma.services.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_EVENT'>
        </action>
        <category
            name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'>
        </category>
        <data
            scheme='nfc'
            host='secure'
            pathPattern='/SIM.*/a0000005595000000000000052414431'>
        </data>
      </intent-filter>
```

And here is the code in which I retrieve the ResolveInfo and the priority:

```
Intent gsmaIntent = new Intent();       
gsmaIntent.setAction("com.gsma.services.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_EVENT");                         
gsmaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
gsmaIntent.setData(Uri.parse("nfc://secure:0/"+ seName+"/"+ strAid));

PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(gsmaIntent,
PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY | PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER);

    ...

if ((resInfo != null) && (resInfo.size() != 0))
{
    for (ResolveInfo res : resInfo)
    {
        intentFilter = res.filter;

        if (intentFilter != null)
        {
            priority = intentFilter.getPriority();
    ...
```

EDIT: Could it be that info is missing for the queryIntentActivities() call?
On my first trial I did not used the PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER flag and hence did not get the IntentFilter data. Is there another flag to retrieve the priority value?

EDIT 2: If the above code cannot work, does anyone know another way to get the   the priority value from an IntentFIlter?

Comment: Is that a standard Android application? If yes, then you surely have wrong syntax in manifest file, because it should be `android:priority="100"`.

Comment: The application is from a third party, and I use ClassyShark to read its manifest. I copied here the information displayed by ClassyShark, and I think the use of **'** is the way ClassyShark choose to display the data ( instead of using **"**).

Comment: Ok, you've decompiled and saw how it was implemented. Then you did the same for your app. What's your app manifest? Pay attention, that not only brackets were the issue, it was not prefixed with `android:` namespace either.

Comment: I know the third party app is not the problem here. I tested it against another app that does the same task (check for priorities) and it works fine. But I don't have access to this app code and cannot see what's wrong with my code.